# End Session When browser is closed in python django and javascript

Tags: javascript, python-3.x, django, session, browser

I have created logout def in python, in that def I am deleting session that I have created after login the user.

I wish to end/del session when the user closes the browser using(X) OR using(alt+4).

how do I call logout url in javascript when user close the browser.

Here is def logout:

```
@login_required
def logout(request):
    username = request.session['username']
    ip = settings.IP
    headers = settings.HEADERS
    del request.session['username']
```

Here is urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('logout', views.logout, name="logout"),
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just set the `SESSION_EXPIRE_AT_BROWSER_CLOSE` setting to true, so that Django's session cookies are only valid for the length of the browser session.

If `SESSION_EXPIRE_AT_BROWSER_CLOSE` is set to True, Django will use browser-length cookies – cookies that expire as soon as the user closes their browser.